# How to zero out small values in an array?

Tags: julia

Is there a generic way to zero out small values in an array?

By "small" I mean elements whose absolute value is less than some threshold like `10.0^-5`.

Edit: For now, I loop with `eachindex`.

```
function sparsify(a, eps)
    for i in eachindex(a)
        if abs(a[i]) < eps
            a[i] = 0
        end 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just apply a mask and an element-wise *less than* operator?

```
>>> x = rand(Float32, 100)
>>> eps = 0.5
>>> x[abs(x) .< eps] = 0
```

or as a function (note the function modifies the vector `x` inplace):

```
>>> sparsify!(x, eps) = x[abs(x) .< eps] = 0;
```

You could also replace `0` with `zero(eltype(x))` to ensure it has the same type as `x`.

The temporary boolean mask created by `x .< eps` will compare every element of `x` to `eps`. Then, every element that satisfies that condition will be set to 0.

Comment: This mask thing is interesting. The problem was not `x .< eps` though but `abs(x) .< eps`, which seems to work. Can you update your solution accordingly?

Comment: BTW, is the exclamation mark a convention for a function that modifies its arguments?

Comment: @Valéry edited the answer to show `abs(x)`, didn't notice that detail, thanks!. And yes, [adding ! to the function is a naming convention](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/style-guide/#append-to-names-of-functions-that-modify-their-arguments) to note that the function internally modifies the parameters. Is completely optional, and there are several posts in the *issues* of github suggesting it might be removed or changed in the future, but by now it is a widely adopted convention (all the julia core functions and most of the packages follow it).

Answer (score 2):

To complete answer of [Imanol Luengo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37102325/2082968), and extend it to multiple dimensions,

```
x[abs.(x) .< eps(eltype(x))] .= zero(eltype(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with a vectorized method, which is much shorter.

```
sparsify(x, eps) = abs(x) < eps ? 0.0 : x
@vectorize_2arg Float64 sparsify
```

Comment: In Julia 1.0, it's unnecessary to explicitly call `@vectorize_2arg`. Instead, add a dot after the function call. E.g., call `sparsify.([a, b, c], eps)`.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer (2019):** The below answer is badly out of date, and refers to an old version of Julia (<0.7). In version 1.x you should instead use `x .= 0` or `fill!(x, 0)`.

What approach to choose depends on what you need. If you just need a simple one-liner, then the vectorized version is fine. But if you want optimal performance, a loop will serve you better.

Here are a few alternatives compared by performance. Do keep in mind that `map` is slow on version 0.4. The timings here are done with version 0.5.

```
function zerofy!(x, vmin)
    for (i, val) in enumerate(x)
        if abs(val) < vmin
            x[i] = zero(eltype(x))
        end
    end
end
zerofy2!(x, vmin) = ( x[abs(x) .< vmin] = zero(eltype(x)) )
zerofy3(x, eps) = abs(x) < eps ? 0.0 : x
@vectorize_2arg Float64 zerofy3!

zerofy4(y, vmin) = map(x -> abs(x)<vmin ? zero(x) : x, y)
zerofy4!(y, vmin) = map!(x -> abs(x)<vmin ? zero(x) : x, y)

function time_zerofy(n, vmin)
    x1 = rand(n)
    x2, x3, x4, x5 = copy(x1), copy(x1), copy(x1), copy(x1)
    @time zerofy!(x1, vmin)
    @time zerofy2!(x2, vmin)
    @time zerofy3(x3, vmin)
    @time zerofy4(x4, vmin)
    @time zerofy4!(x5, vmin)
    return nothing
end

julia> time_sparse(10^8, 0.1)
  0.122510 seconds
  1.078589 seconds (73.25 k allocations: 778.590 MB, 5.42% gc time)
  0.558914 seconds (2 allocations: 762.940 MB)
  0.688640 seconds (5 allocations: 762.940 MB)
  0.243921 seconds
```

There's a pretty big difference between the loop (fastest) and the naively vectorized one.

Edit: `zerofy3!` => `zerofy3` since it's not in-place.

Comment: I've tried testing the above with Julia 1.1.1 and have discovered some discrepancies. In the for loop, it should be `for (i, val) in enumerate(x)` as the indices are provided first. The second works like this: `zerofy2!(x, vmin) = ( x[abs.(x) .< vmin] .= zero(eltype(x)) )`. I couldn't get `zerofy3`, `zerofy4`, or `zerofy4!` to function. The timing still appears to be the same though, the first one runs faster than the second. `(0.876196 versus 0.977687)`

Comment: This answer refers to an old version of Julia. You are correct that I used `enumerate` wrong, but the entire answer is badly out of date. For example, the `@vectorize_2arg` macro no longer exists, and there are now better ways of doing this (e.g. just write `x .= 0`, or use `fill!`.) I'll add a disclaimer at the top.